# A problem to use function for get count(*) in pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i have a problem to use `pdo` for get `COUNT(*)`.

```php
    (...)

    public function getRowCount($sql, $bin = null)
    {
        $a = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
        if (!is_null($bin)) {
            foreach ($bin as $i => $val) {
                $a->bindParam(":$i", $val);
            }
        }
        $a->execute();
        return $a->fetchColumn();
    }

    (...)
```

**If I use this, it works for me :**

```php
    // $obj = new class()
    echo $obj->getRowCount("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `table_name` WHERE `a`=:a", [
        'a' => 'ABC'
    ]);

    // 1 or 2 and ...
```

**But it doesn't work with two conditions :**

```php
    // $obj = new class()
    echo $obj->getRowCount("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `table_name` WHERE `a`=:a AND `b`=:b", [
        'a' => 'ABC',
        'b' => 'DEF'
    ]);

    // only 0
```

Comment: maybe you don't have any record with those values?..

Comment: no it's not ..!

Comment: dump the values you are injecting in the query and run the query manually

Comment: The most likely explanation is that the database doesn't contain any matching rows. Show us the table data you are using with this, and we can tell you what your query would expect to output. Or as Berto99 says, run your query manually in mysql directly and see what it produces.

Comment: Thanks **@ADyson** and **@Berto99**.  I need to use `BindParam` in the loop and I don't want to use this manually. There is no problem with manual use in pdo, so data and records are not a problem.

Comment: Sorry I think I misunderstood the loop part. Anyway you don't need the loop, just pass the existing array to ->execute() directly - it's already in the correct format for that. Demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9fa99811e28f323ebfe598b63dd0bf7e8f256eb2

Comment: OK **@ADyson** . Thanks for your solution!